# Access to r_fullprofile scope with profile APIs

Tags: linkedin-api

I have already created an app, for the integration, I need to build, I need r_fullprofile scope access. But I do not see any way to get it and enable it for my app.
Can someone please guide?

Be able to access information like education, job experince, etc.